# Some paragraph elements not showing on page

Tags: html

Edit: the page works correctly in Firefox Incognito.  Not with Chrome with an ad blocker, but I don't know what the ad blocker could be picking up on to block.

The last two paragraph elements don't show up when I open this in my browser. I have no CSS.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>ID = 7615493245_Karin_Johnson_25-Day_02-18-2022</p>
  <h1>Name = Karin Johnson</h1>
  <h1>Report type = 25-Day Report</h1>
  <h1>Total impressions = 5574</h1>
  <p>Percentage of Impressions = 111%</p>
  <h1>Device Impressions:</h1>
  <p> Other Devices: 5</p>
  <p> iPhone: 2174</p>
  <p> Android: 723</p>
  <p> Tablet: 110</p>
  <p> Desktop: 163</p>
  <h1>Impressions by Gender:</h1>
  <p> Female: 2823</p>
  <p> Male: 2750</p>
  <h1>Impressions by Age:</h1>
  <p> Age 18 - 24: 293</p>
  <p> Age 25 - 34: 889</p>
  <p> Age 35 - 44: 860</p>
  <p> Age 45 - 54: 519</p>
  <p> Age 55 - 64: 410</p>
  <p> Age 65+: 204</p>
  <h1>Links to your Ads:</h1>
  <p> Google Ad: https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/64638361866/</p>
  <p> Facebook Ad: https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/60988332149/</p>
  <p> Instagram Ad: https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/64640044824/</p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I see at the bottom of the rendered page:
[image]

This is what I see when I check the page source in my browser:
[image]

But this is what I see when I "inspect" with my browser:
[image]

And expanded, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot and/or the rendered HTML from your browser's developer tools. Also, to clarify, when you say "the last 2 `p` sections" are you referring to "Facebook Ad" and "Instagram Ad"?

Comment: Yes, the Facebook Ad and Instagram Ad don't show up when I open this code in a chrome browser

Comment: Can you inspect the page's HTML using your browser's developer tools and attach a screenshot of that? Looking to confirm that the HTML is even on the page, or if there's some browser styling that's hiding overflowed content or something.

Comment: To add to wounded's comments - "view source" only shows what the server sent. Devtools will show everything, ie what JavaScript created.

Comment: Which browser you use?

Comment: Those two images essentially show the same thing. I see a heading followed by three paragraphs.

Comment: Won't let me edit the post to say Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions running (e.g. AdBlock)? Have you tried opening the page in incognito mode?

Comment: It works correctly in Firefox incognito.  What's the problem with the code as it's written?  What would Chrome with extensions be picking up on?  I have an ad blocker, origin.

Comment: So it was an extension as I had suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the ad link in a `iframe` tag to see what appears. Something like this:

```
Google Ad: <iframe src="https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/64638361866/" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/christian2033/pen/OJOKOvB)

Comment: That works, but why?

Comment: I think it's because it shows a preview. And this preview works like a webpage or a document, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox by the way. Maybe another option to try: `<p> Google Ad: <a href="https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/64638361866/">https://app.hubspot.com/file-preview/4871530/file/64638361866/</a></p>` to see if it renders the link.

Answer (score 1):

Some Ad Blockers identify suspicius links and words like "ad" and prevent them from showing.